# How to update editext in adapter using plus and minus button in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, adapter

[image]

I updating data from server and putting on editext using ArrayAdapter. But I am updaing using plus(p) and minus(m) button, see on
the picture. but unable to update. any idea how to do this?

For Plus:

```
holder.imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int currentQty = Integer.parseInt(newDataItems.get(position).qty.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < listEdit.size(); i++) {
                    if (position==i)) {
                        int finalQty = currentQty + 1;
                        holder.etShoppingCartQty.setText(""+finalQty);
                        //listEdit.get(i).setText("" + finalQty);

                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

For MinusButton listener :

```
int finalQty = currentQty - 1
```

and **Automatically update total value.** whenever click Plus and Minus button.

Comment: your adapter code please

Comment: add `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `Button` click after `for` loop executes

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps :

1. You need handle the click listener in your adapter for P and M
   button.
2. Increase or Decrease the value of EditText in onClickListener of
   Button P and M.
3. Also Set the Increased or Decreased value to list in onClickListener of P and M Buttons.

**Update based on your code :**

```
holder.imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int currentQty = Integer.parseInt(newDataItems.get(position).qty.toString());
                int finalQty = currentQty + 1;
                //holder.etShoppingCartQty.setText(""+finalQty);
                newDataItems.get(position).setQty(finalQty);
                notifyDataSetChanged();    
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter set listener to buttons when bind to itemview (get view).

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        ...inflate
    }
    //I love ViewHolder pattern, you can not use it
    final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(vh);
    vh.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListaner(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //as your example
            int currentQty = Integer.parseInt(newDataItems.get(position).qty.toString());
            currentQty++;

            //...update data (qty), do work to save data changes in model

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            // or vh.editText.setText("" + currentQty); if you no need to update data
        }
    });
    return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting your own code :) with minor tweaks

```
holder.imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int currentQty = Integer.parseInt(newDataItems.get(position).qty.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < listEdit.size(); i++) {
                if (position==i)) {
                    int finalQty = currentQty + 1;
                    holder.etShoppingCartQty.setText(""+finalQty);
                    // Uncommenting below line
                    listEdit.get(i).setText("" + finalQty);

                }

            }
        // To notify adapter that data set has been changed
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```